# LastModifiedDate or SystemModstamp: Which one to verify for concurrent modification exception?

Tags: apex, integration, system-fields, lastmodifieddate

I have a integration requirement where from external system salesforce records can be updated. So, before updating we need to verify if the record has been modified by some other user/process.

Is that wiser to verify only  `SystemModstamp` field value of the record instead of `LastModifiedDate`?

2nd thing, `SystemModstamp` is readonly and it is not view-able from UI, whereas `LastModifiedDate` is view-able at UI page layout.

Since there could be a mismatch in values between those two, then why Salesforce has not exposed that at UI where `SystemModstamp` covers most updated than other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemModStamp is more accurate. It includes not just updates from the UI/API, but also updates from the system, such as changing picklist values. Also, LastModifiedDate can be spoofed, and so is not strictly truth in regards to records that have been uploaded but never modified.

You'll want to read [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html) about the differences, but basically you should always use SystemModStamp anyways, because it is indexed and therefore has better performance than LastModifiedDate (when using = or > comparisons though, the system covertly uses SystemModStamp when you use LastModifiedDate).

I suspect that SystemModStamp is not exposed in the UI because it is primarily for integrations/API/code to determine the "true" last modification time, especially when you're talking about data replication.

Then again, if this is an *external* integration, consider simply using the [replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm). It's guaranteed to catch any in-flight records so that your system won't miss any rows of data.