# Is there a way to find a Case based on Task?

Tags: soql, case

Specifically the case with the most recent activity tied to it.

I have tried the following queries:

```
SELECT Case.Id FROM Task ORDER BY LastModifiedDate LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE WhatID = '(SELECT Id FROM Task ORDER BY LASTMODIFIEDDATE DESC LIMIT 1)'
```

But it doesn't seem like the case has the `WhatId` column.

Comment: Tasks does not support inner joins, so I guess you might need to do two queries. Here it is listed as an idea- [Support Task For Semi Join Inner Selects](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000J68oAAC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can find the Case based on the task this way

```
SELECT WhatId FROM Task 
WHERE Id = '00T0n000002jllt' 
and What.Type = 'Case'
```

> The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

According to your requirement, below is the query:

```
SELECT WhatId FROM Task 
WHERE What.Type = 'Case'
ORDER BY SystemModStamp LIMIT 1
```

Use `SystemModStamp` instead of `LastModifiedDate` because this is indexed field and provides more accurate information. Refer this [LastModifiedDate or SystemModstamp: Which one to verify for concurrent modification exception?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155773/lastmodifieddate-or-systemmodstamp-which-one-to-verify-for-concurrent-modificat)

Comment: This is the best answer, but he did specify he wanted it ordered by last modified date so should remove the id from the where and add order by lastmodified date desc

Comment: @Toby, better to use `SystemModStamp`, I have updated my answer